# New to sass, expecting expected selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Im new to sass and tried some code:

```
$blue: #3bbfce
$margin: 16px

.content-navigation
border-color: $blue
color: darken($blue, 9%)

.border
 padding: $margin / 2
 margin: $margin / 2
 border-color: $blue
```

But now in my rails app i get this error:

```
 Invalid CSS after "$margin": expected selector or at-rule, was ": 16px"
```

Whats wrong?

---

Now i tried something with zurb:

```
.your-class-name {
  @include button;
  @include dropdown-button($padding, $pip-color, $base-style);
}
```

But now i get the error

```
  Undefined mixin 'dropdown-button'.
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing SASS and SCSS style syntax within the same file.  You must pick one or the other.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're missing semicolons after your style declarations. You also need to encapsulate selector declarations within curly brackets:

```
$blue: #3bbfce;
$margin: 16px;

.content-navigation {
  border-color: $blue;
  color: darken($blue, 9%);
}

.border {
  padding: $margin / 2;
  margin: $margin / 2;
  border-color: $blue;
}
```

You might like to read over [this primer](http://sass-lang.com/) from the creators of SASS.

Comment: Since it worked, would you kindly consider accepting this answer as correct?

Comment: Yes in 3 minutes! I cant upvote it because i dont have 15 points! But one more thing, i updatet my question, because im getting an new error!

Comment: The `Undefined mixin 'dropdown-button'` error indicates that you haven't yet imported the mixin called `dropdown-button`. Check that you have, and that it's a valid import. And FYI, you now have 17 rep points...